# $[0,n]$ continuous function problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. $f$ is a real valued function, defined and continuous on $[0,n]$ and $f(0)=f(n)$. Prove that there exists $x_1,x_2\in [0,n]$, so that $x_1-x_2=1$ and $f(x_2)=f(x_1)$.

Hints on how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using induction?

Comment: @user176744: What about if $n=0$?

Comment: I'm guessing that they don't define $0$ as a natural number

Comment: question is posed to me as $n\in \mathbb{N}$ not $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: @user176744 In some countries, it's usual to have $\Bbb N=\{0, 1, \dots\}$. That's why this question about $0\in\Bbb N$ arises quite often on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Assuming you meant continuous functions from $[0,n]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, consider a new function
$$ g(x) = f(1+x)-f(x), \forall x\in[0,n-1]$$.

Try and prove that $g(x)$ is continuous and crosses zero. So, $\exists x\in[0,n-1]$ such that $f(1+x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Looks obscure at first sight, but it's indeed a valuable hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is incomplete; consider the map
$$f:\ [0,2]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}^2:\ x\ \longmapsto (\cos(\pi x),\sin(\pi x)).$$
It is clear that $f$ is continuous and that $f(0)=f(2)$, but for $x_1,x_2\in[0,2]$ we have $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ if and only if $x_1,x_2\in\{0,2\}$. In particular we cannot have $x_1-x_2=1$.

Comment: Why is your $f$ going to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Comment: OP did not specify the codomain of the function.

Comment: I edited the question, as it's most probably what the OP meant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Shash's answer:

Notice that due to Rolle's theorem, we know there is $\xi \in (0,n)$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$.

Suppose wlog that $f(\xi)$ is local maximum, and $\xi >1$.

In that case, $g(0)=f(1)-f(0)$ is larger than zero, because $1$ is on the way $\xi$ and the function is ascending.

That also means that $g(n-1)=f(n)-f(n-1)$ is negative due to a similar argument.

$g$ is continuous, $g(0)*g(n-1) <0$, this means (think bisection method) that there is $\psi \in (0,n-1)$ such that $g(\psi)=0$. this means that $f(1+\psi)=f(\psi)$, and we are done.

Disclaimer: this argument succeeds if $f(\xi)$ is local minimum / maximum.
In that case that it isn't (meaning $f''(x)=0$) then I'm not 100% sure that what you are trying to prove holds).

Disclaimer 2: The assumption that $\xi >1$ is important and non trivial. even if $f(\xi)$ is local extremum, if $\xi <1$ then my proof won't work.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: Well I already assumed so many assumptions, might just as well add one more to the list...